# Have Firefox remember Z order and use that to select which tab gets focus when the current tab is closed

Tags: firefox

I have three tabs open: Tab1, Tab2, and Tab3.

I'm on Tab2 and middle click on a link to open in a new tab (Tab4).

I go to Tab4 to read what was opened there.

With Tab4 still having focus, I close it.

At this point, how can I have focus return to Tab2 since it was most recent in Z order, not Tab3 as Firefox defaults to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the main reasons I use [tab mix plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the add-on *[LastTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/lasttab/)*. If I understand your dilemma correctly, it should do what you want it to and also provide some customizable configuration as well.

Otherwise, I'm sure there it can be altered somewhere in `about:config`.